# Eric-IDE version 7 Installation problems

Tags: python, eric-ide

My operating system is Linux Mint.  I've recently updated to version 21.  During the updating process certain packages are removed by the installer.  One such package was Eric7.  I have tried to install it using their Install.py script but I've hit a snag that I don't understand.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/eric7/eric7install.json'

I've check the dist-package folder and it is empty.  The /eric7/eric7install.json was probably removed by the OS update process.  I don't know how to correct the situation.

I have tried the virtual environment route as suggested by their website and the process seems to have work since there in an entry in the system menu but the click on the item doesn't work.  I do not know how to execute Eric7 using the eric7_venv.

I hope some can help because I do like the Eric IDE for python programming.

Comment: Reinstalled Eric using the installation from there Website.  Application will not execute correctly.  Executed from the terminal, received the following information:
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimalegl, eglfs, offscreen, minimal, wayland-egl, vkkhrdisplay, linuxfb, xcb, wayland, vnc.

Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Thanks Loeffel !   The installation of libxcb-cursor0 has solved my problem. Eric7 executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
Try to install the `libxcb-cursor0` package. It worked for me.
Props to https://www.mail-archive.com/eric@riverbankcomputing.com/msg04538.html